# How to create breadcrumb in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breadcrumbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can dynamic breadcrumbs be achieved with ASP.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066777/how-can-dynamic-breadcrumbs-be-achieved-with-asp-net-mvc)

I want to create breadcrumb for my whole application in asp.net mvc. I have idea of how to create sitemap control in asp.net but how to create in asp.net mvc?

Comment: see [How can dynamic breadcrumbs be achieved with ASP.net MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066777/how-can-dynamic-breadcrumbs-be-achieved-with-asp-net-mvc)