# Indicate "Where am I at" for any page in a Web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Web application has a very deep structure in terms of menu tree, having one menu option going down 3 or 4 levels.

For example, consider the following tree from the menu item **Application**:

- Application

  - Modules

    - Sections

      - Section_Ads

        - Ads_Config

By entering an Application named *As01* inside the Application menu item we go down to see its modules. Consequently if we create or edit a Module, inside we can create Sections for it and inside those sections we can add advertisement and so on.

So let's imagine we are inside the Section_ads menu item and we chose the Application As01, the Module Mod01, the Section Sect01 and now we see the respective Section_Ads pages for it.
I would like to show the user a path with links to point where the user is in the application, like this:

As01 -> Mod01 -> Sect01

By having the above, he could easily go back to the page of the application As01 to review its Modules or go back to the Modules page for that application to choose another sector or even create a new one.

How can this be achieved in an elegant and efficient way?

Comment: It sounds like the [SiteMapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.aspx) control is something you want to look into.

Comment: I just looked into it but there's something I didn't understand. My URLs are dynamically constructed according to the items chosen in the page. If I am at the 3rd level down, will this control retain the URL it used to have when it was at the 2nd level? For example, the url for the 2nd level is www.foo.org/2ndlvl?id=feofkfd923ap and now at the 3rd level we got www.foo.org/2ndlvl/3rdlvl?id=ofijas2i342

Comment: Sorry, I'm not extremely familiar with the details (and didn't realize your pages were dynamic).  I have just seen people use it for site navigation - which is why I commented instead of putting an answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're asking under ASP.NET MVC and not Javascript, I would recommend searching for existing questions on breadcrumbs in ASP.NET MVC. And here is what you get!

[How can dynamic breadcrumbs be achieved with ASP.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066777/how-can-dynamic-breadcrumbs-be-achieved-with-asp-net-mvc)

And there are also helpful results in the related questions on that question as well.

Comment: Let me look into that question and I'll get back at you soon, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

search for breadcrumps implementation, number of APIs help achieve it. Yahoo APi is one.