# How to create a dynamic breadcrumb navigation for .net core razor pages?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, razor-pages

Im trying to create a breadcrumb navigation, i.e.

```
Home > Contact
```

I have found this answer - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26439510/4353708)

But it seams to be for MVC rather than razor pages. And i cant seam to find anything that works with razor pages.

Thanks in advance :)

## Answer

As my answer was deleted by a moderator, here was my soloution -

> To solve this I found this project -
> https://github.com/zHaytam/SmartBreadcrumbs
>
> Very easy to use and worked flawlessly

Comment: First off: MVC and Razor are not mutually exclusive. Razor is the view engine you are using with MVC as the framework. That answer did have a section for razor that you should be able to use. "In razor view, we don't need Html.Raw, as Razor takes care of escaping when dealing with IHtmlContent:". Did you try implementing the razor solution in your project?

Comment: @Dean Razor Pages is a different development model to MVC: https://www.learnrazorpages.com . It's built on top of the ASP.NET Core MVC framework.

Comment: I created a little library for ASP.NET Core, you can look at how I did it and implement it for Razor Pages (I believe the only part to change is the url creation, since there is no controller/action anymore). https://github.com/zHaytam/SmartBreadcrumbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I found this project - https://github.com/zHaytam/SmartBreadcrumbs

1. Simply install the NuGet package `Install-Package SmartBreadcrumbs`
2. Initialize it  in the startup `services.AddBreadcrumbs(GetType().Assembly);`
3. In `_ViewImports.cshtml`, add `@addTagHelper *, SmartBreadcrumbs`
4. In your `_Layout.cshml` (or specific pages), use `<breadcrumb></breadcrumb>`.
5. On your default/ home page, add this annotation to the class `[DefaultBreadcrumb("Home")]`
6. And on other pages add this to the class `[Breadcrumb("Bookings")]`
7. Add if you want to link to a prevouse page add this to the class `[Breadcrumb("Details", FromPage = typeof(IndexModel))]`

Then if you want to customize the look of it simply update the start by adding the CSS classes you want to use -

```cs
services.AddBreadcrumbs(GetType().Assembly, options =>
{
    options.TagName = "nav";
    options.TagClasses = "";
    options.OlClasses = "breadcrumb";
    options.LiClasses = "breadcrumb-item";
    options.ActiveLiClasses = "breadcrumb-item active";
    options.SeparatorElement = "<li class=\"separator\">/</li>";
});
```

Comment: Note that Blazor is not supported yet by this component, perhaps in a later version (that would be great).

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem and solved it in this way:

At first I made a `razor` component for Breadcrumb like below:

```
 <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" style="background-color: #f2f2f3">
    <div class="mt-max-size">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            @foreach (var link in Links.OrderBy(x => x.OrderIndex))
            {
                if (link.IsActive)
                {
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active mt-bread-item" aria-current="page">@link.Title</li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a class="mt-bread-item-link" href="@link.Address">@link.Title</a></li>
                }
            }
        </ol>
    </div>
</nav>
    @code{
        [Parameter]
        public List<Model.BreadcrumbLink> Links { get; set; }
        public Breadcrumb()
        {
    
        }
            protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync() => base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
```

And then I have used this component in my `razor` layout like below:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<Breadcrumb Links="@breadcrumbLinks" />

@code{
    private string currentUrl;
protected override void OnParametersSet() {
        breadcrumbLinks = new List<Model.BreadcrumbLink>();
        currentUrl = NavigationManager.Uri;
        var myUrl = currentUrl.Replace(NavigationManager.BaseUri, "");
        breadcrumbLinks.Add(new Model.BreadcrumbLink
        {
            Address = NavigationManager.BaseUri,
            IsActive = NavigationManager.Uri == NavigationManager.BaseUri,
            OrderIndex = 1,
            Title = @Localizer["Home".ToLower()]
        });
        var path = myUrl.Split('/');
        var count = 1;
        
        foreach (var link in path)
        {
            if (link == "") continue;
            count++;
            var lastLink = breadcrumbLinks.Last();
            breadcrumbLinks.Add(new Model.BreadcrumbLink
            {
                Address = $"{lastLink.Address}/{link}",
                IsActive = link == path.Last(),
                OrderIndex = count,
                Title = link
            });
        }
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

Note: To pass the data I Have created a model: `Model.BreadcrumbLink`. You can see its definition below :

```
public class BreadcrumbLink
    {
        public int OrderIndex { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

I hope it be helpful !!

Comment: Interesting implementation that can be suitable for a Blazor project. Could you post a fiddle to show how it looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Razor Pages routing is based on the file structure in the Pages folder, you could just use that as the basis of generating breadcrumbs. Or you could use `Context.Request.Path` and split on the `/` to obtain the segments of the navigation. This could be very simple if you have a default (Index) document in every folder within the Pages folder. Otherwise you will have to check to see if files exist before rendering each crumb.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, did try creating it using this approach, but didn't get very far. I might look at this again sometime in the future

Comment: I did a similar path as suggested by this answer in my repo if you want to take a look: https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate/blob/master/src/BlazorBoilerplate.CommonUI/Shared/Components/Breadcrumbs.razor

Comment: Here is the latest source: https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate/blob/d193212d3ffaf9274693879ab8474ed3b06c9805/src/Shared/Modules/BlazorBoilerplate.Theme.Material/Shared/Components/Breadcrumbs.razor, but might want to check if Blazor now has better functionality now