# How to change a URL Link in ASP.NET MVC Breadcrumb

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I found a nice answer on creating breadcrumbs for this project here:

[How can dynamic breadcrumbs be achieved with ASP.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066777/153923)

The modified code that I am using is here:

```cs
public static string BuildBreadcrumbNavigation(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    var controllerName = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    if ((controllerName != "Home") && (controllerName != "Account"))
    {
        var htmlLink = helper.ActionLink(
            linkText: "Home",
            actionName: "/",
            controllerName: "Home").ToHtmlString();

        var sb = new StringBuilder($"<ol class='breadcrumb'><li>{htmlLink}</li>");

        var controllerLink = helper.ActionLink(
            linkText: controllerName,
            actionName: "/",
            controllerName: controllerName);

        sb.Append($"<li>{controllerLink}</li>");

        var actionName = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

        var actionLink = helper.ActionLink(
            linkText: actionName,
            actionName: actionName,
            controllerName: controllerName);

        sb.Append($"<li>{actionLink}</li>");

        result = sb.Append("</ol>").ToString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

The webpage I want to implement it on has a navigation menu:

- Services

  - Parts
  - Bulletins
  - Publications
  - Warranty
- Sales

  - Buyers
  - Image Resources
  - Videos

For something like `Home > Services > Parts`, there is a controller called **ServiceController.cs** and a model called **PartsInformation.cs**.

The links for `Home` and `Parts` work fine, but there is nothing to display for the intermediate `Services` because it is a menu item only. Clicking `Services` attempts to redirect here:

https://localhost:44383/Services/

[image: 404]

What should be done here?

Should I remove the link for `Services` and leave the text, or should I have `Services` route to `Home`?

I would like to route the root navigation menu items back to `Home`, but I don't understand enough about this [ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Comment: I would make a custom attribute in which to override the OnActionExecuting method and replace the route value with whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://localhost:44383/Services/

It is trying to redirect to [default action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-up-conventional-route) of `ServiceController`, which is typically named `Index`.

I think you have a few options (depending on what you want):

1. Redirect to `/Home`:

   ```cs
   public class ServiceController : Controller
   {
       // assuming you want to redirect to HomeController's default action:
       public IActionResult Index() => Redirect("/Home");

       // or if you know HomeController's default action name,
       // you can use more idiomatic syntax:
       //
       // public IActionResult Index() => RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
   ```
2. Utilize this space by adding an action Index page under Services (with list of services).
3. Render `Services` in breadcrumb as text (instead of link):

   ```cs
   if (controllerName == "Services")
   {
       sb.Append($"<li>{controllerName}</li>");
   }
   else
   {
       var controllerLink = helper.ActionLink(
           linkText: controllerName,
           actionName: "/",
           controllerName: controllerName);

       sb.Append($"<li>{controllerLink}</li>");
   }
   ```

(I'd personally choose option #2 if it's my decision)

Comment: Let me think on this. There are hundreds of links in the Navigation Menu, not just the 5 or 6 that I listed. I'd rather not have to go in and edit each of those hundreds of controllers because they don't happen to have method matching `public ActionResult Index()`.

Comment: You could use reflection in a static constructor of class containing `BuildBreadcrumbNavigation()` method to construct a map of all available controllers and their corresponding actions in your app; as in `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969888/863980. Reflection is expensive, but this way it will execute once per application run. Then replace `if (controllerName == "Services")` condition with `if (!s_controllerActionMap.ContainsKey(controllerName) || !s_controllerActionMap[controllerName].Contains(actionName)) { /* render text instead of link */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done until someone posts a better solution:

In the file `Global.asax.cs`, I added the **Application_Error** method to redirect when a controller is not found:

```cs
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var err = Server.GetLastError();
    if (err.GetType() == typeof(InvalidOperationException))
    {
        if (err.Message.IndexOf("The view 'Index' or its master was not found") == 0)
        {
            if (-1 < err.StackTrace.IndexOf("System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)"))
            {
                // this controller does not have a view
                var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                var homeLink = $"{request.Url.Scheme}://{request.Url.Authority}{request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/')}/";
                Response.Redirect(homeLink);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but it just doesn't seem like the way ASP.NET MVC should handle the case of links going to controllers that do not exist.